# UWP app release version hangs on splash screen?

Tags: c#, windows-10

Debug versions (86, 64, ARM) all work fine, release versions build fine, but when they run all that happens is my app window opens and remains blank (white background). The only errors I see in the output are a whole bunch of:

```
 ...PDB file was not present when IL code was compiled to native.
```

I'm not sure if the missing .pdb files are the culprit - pretty sure they're not, cause they're just for debugging purposes right?
Anyways, this is the first UWP app I have tried to get ready for the Windows Store, and not completely sure if I have to do anything special like sign it to test release versions on my own computer?

Edit 1: Thank you @Alan for your suggestions, manually uninstalling the app sometimes gets me past the blank window to load the app bar, but then I am getting these errors when it doesn't hang on the splash screen:

[Debugger Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnpfc.png),
[Debugger Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjItz.png)

I have done nothing special to the splash screen, loaded all my visual assets using the built in tools in manifest, and have not modified App.xaml.cs from its default. Here is my Mainpage.cs:

```
 using Sublist.Classes;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

 namespace Sublist
 {

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string TAG = "MainPage: ";

    // for loading and saving user data and settings
    public static DataHandler dataHandler;

    public static MasterList<Entry> masterList;
    //public static int listViewSelectedIndex = -1;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        dataHandler = new DataHandler(this);
        masterList = new MasterList<Entry>();

        // load user data
        if (dataHandler.userDataList != null)
            masterList = dataHandler.userDataList;

        masterList.UpdateListView(this);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dataHandler.LoadUserSettings();
    }


    private void AppBarAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        masterList.AddRow(this);
    }

    private void AppBarRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(mainListView.SelectedIndex < 0))
        {
            masterList.RemoveRow(this);
        }
    }

    private void AppBarMoveDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AppBarMoveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AppBarIndent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // indent the row control if currently selected index is a list view item
        if (-1 < mainListView.SelectedIndex && mainListView.SelectedIndex < mainListView.Items.Count)
        {
            // but don't allow more than one indent past above row's indent level
            RowControl rc = (RowControl)mainListView.Items[mainListView.SelectedIndex];
            int indexMinus1 = mainListView.SelectedIndex - 1;
            if (-1 < indexMinus1 && rc.indentProp <= masterList[indexMinus1].indent)
            {
                rc.indentProp++;
            }
        }
        // then update list view
        masterList.UpdateListView(this);
    }

    private void AppBarUnindent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // unindent the row control if currently selected index is a list view item
        if (-1 < mainListView.SelectedIndex && mainListView.SelectedIndex < mainListView.Items.Count)
        {
            // but don't allow unindenting off left side of page
            RowControl rc = (RowControl)mainListView.Items[mainListView.SelectedIndex];
            if (rc.indentProp > 0)
            {
                rc.indentProp--;
            }
        }
        // then update list view
        masterList.UpdateListView(this);
    }

    public void AppBarShowCompl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataHandler.SaveUserSettings();

        masterList.UpdateListView(this);
    }

    public void AppBarMarkAsCompleted_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // toggle hidden state of active entry
        if (-1 < mainListView.SelectedIndex && mainListView.SelectedIndex < masterList.Count)
        {
            masterList[mainListView.SelectedIndex].completed = (masterList[mainListView.SelectedIndex].completed) ? false : true;

            masterList.UpdateListView(this);
        }
    }

}
}
```

I have added the FileService and SettingsService classes from the opensource Template10 to the project.

The build setting "compile with .NET Native tool chain" was unchecked, I've tried deploying with it checked/unchecked for both debug/release versions, and now the debug version also often hangs on the splash screen? With it checked, I get a whole bunch of these errors as well:

```
'Sublist.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\biwinrt.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
```

I've tried downloading the server symbols with no success...

Comment: I've tried many MS official samples and my own projects in release mode, but didn't experience this issue. Try manually uninstall the app first, and deploy the release mode build again. And to narrow down the issue, see what happens if you uncheck the "Compile with .Net Native tool chain" on the Build tab of project's property page. And more details about what(3rd party/open source) have been used, and anything special you've done with splash screen, start page or something in App.xaml.cs may help others to understand.

Comment: Try to find out where the hang(or the unhandled exception) happens. If you didn't do anything special in app.xaml.cs, try comment out all code expect for  this.InitializeComponent(); and see what happens. To get more debugging info for debug version, change debugger type to Mixed in Debug tab of project's property page. You will be able to get COM error code in the visual studio output window. You can check the stack trace by view the content of "e" in your first screenshot.

Comment: I mean comment out code in mainpage's constructor. all or part of them to identify which part will cause the issue. I guess the issue should be related to the DataHandler and MasterList. If it is the case and you cannot figure out what the problem is. try to simplify the implementation and provide the code that can be used for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok after more troubleshooting, it seems that the problem is compiling with .NET Native tool chain. What does this mean exactly? I don't understand the difference between doing this (release version) and not doing it (debug version)?

Comment: Here is a link to Sublist on github: https://github.com/toadlyBroodle/Sublist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the hang happens at the following line in GetIfFileExitsAsync.

```
retval = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(key);
```

I made the following change in you code and it should work now.

In DataHandler's constructor, use Task.Run to initialize the userDataList.

```
public DataHandler(MainPage mp)
{
    mainPage = mp;

    settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
    fileHelper = new FileHelper();

    LoadUserSettings();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        userDataList = LoadUserData();
    });
    Task.WaitAll();
}
```

I am still not sure why the .net native compile will make this issue, but will try to simplify the project and report it in MS internal channel.

Comment: Ok thanks, this does fix the hang, but calling LoadUserData() inside Task.Run() doesn't allow read access to the local folder for some reason, so doing it this way doesn't allow loading of user data?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot about what error you saw on specific code line?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get good debugging information when compiling the release version (using .NET Native tool chain). Here are some [errors](http://imgur.com/XvCIZl4) I am getting that I don't know what to do with. You can recreate it by cloning the repository if you want.

Comment: uncheck the optimize code check box in project properties page will enable you to debug the release build.

Comment: And pls let me know what are the exact steps you have done to repro the issue. I didn't encounter any issue by simply pressing + and - buttons on your app.

Comment: I just got your new code by cloning the repository. And it works very good when I do: click + -> type 12345 -> mark as completed. Go to C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Packages\Sublist-efd892e9-684c-4b3c-8732-cb831162ad86_jc9nmjjyb59q4\LocalState, and found userdata.txt is created and has this content -- [{"$type":"Sublist.Classes.Entry, Sublist","id":0,"parentID":0,"listViewIndex":-1,"indent":0,"bulletButtonChecked":false,"textboxText":"12345","completed":true,"hidden":false}]

Comment: Ok, you're right, the problem is that because the data is loaded asyncronously now, before it can complete, SaveUserData() is called and overwrites the existing blank state over the saved file. So once I ensure this doesn't happen, all should be well! Thanks so much for your help with this!